# Dodge Ram 2500 gasoline won't run after key starts

Tags: starting, dodge, ram, ignition-key

So my old keys start and run fine. I had a new key cut, it works fine in the door and starts ignition fine but the engine cuts out within seconds of starting. The old keys keep it running just fine. It seems there is a cut out for some reason, is there a way to bypass this? I have a regular key cut as well as a sure grip and the engine cuts out after starting on both. Any ideas?

Comment: What year is your Dodge Ram?

Comment: Door plate says manufactured in 4-04

Comment: .....and I found out its a chip key, DOH!

Comment: I kind of figured that, but needed the model year to figure out how to get it to be recognized. I take it you don't know if the new key is a unregistered chipped key or not?

Answer (score 2):

For your edification in case you want to try this. Here are the procedures for getting the vehicle to *learn* the new key. There are some disclaimers/actions you need to pay attention to, so read the entire procedure ***before*** you try to do this. If your key is a completely metal key, it will not have a chip inside of it. If it looks like the image below, it probably is chipped. I completely pulled this procedure from [the Dodgetalk.com forum](http://www.dodgetalk.com/forums/showthread.php?t=367352):

> Disclaimer: All of the "customer learn" procedures for programming new keys REQUIRE the vehicle to have at least two keys pre-programmed and on hand to use BEFORE programming new keys to the vehicle! IF YOU DO NOT HAVE TWO KEYS ALREADY PROGRAMMED TO THE VEHICLE YOU WILL NEED TO HAVE THE DEALER OR AN INDEPENDENT REPAIR FACILITY WITH THE FACTORY SCANTOOL(S) PROGRAM THE SECOND KEY.
>
> **2002/3-2005** The early third gen vehicle keys/fobs look like this...

[image][image]

> The vehicles that do not have remote keyless entry (RKE) still have a chip inside the key, this system is called the sentry key immobilizer system (SKIS). The key sends a signal to the sentry key immobilizer module (SKIM) which allows the ignition to start the vehicle.
>
> The SKIM in every new vehicle is pre-programmed with 2 keys from the factory. The system allows up to 8 keys to be programmed to a single vehicle. If you have your two factory keys and would like to add more, below is the step by step instruction.
>
> PROGRAMMING A SENTRY KEY
>
> 1. Insert one of the two programmed sentry keys into the ignition and turn it to the ON position.
> 2. After the ignition switch has been on ON for about 3 seconds, but no more than 15 seconds, turn the ignition OFF and remove the first key. Insert the second programmed sentry key and turn the ignition to ON for at least 3 seconds again, but no more than 15 seconds. Leave the second key in with the ignition on ON.
>
> ***THE KEY SWAPPING STEPS MUST BE DONE WITHIN 15 SECONDS OF EACH OTHER.***
>
> 3. In about 10 seconds the VTSS (single red anti-theft light on the cluster) will begin to flash, indicating it has entered "customer learn" mode.
> 4. Within 60 seconds of entering learn mode, turn the ignition OFF and remove the programmed key. Insert a blank sentry key and turn the ignition to ON. In about 10 seconds the VTSS light will stop flashing and stay on solid for about 3 seconds, then turn off indicating it has programmed the new key. The vehicle will now exit learn mode. Turn the key to OFF and leave the ignition off for 60 seconds.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly they key AND fob that I have. I just bit the bullet and went and got another made and it works just fine now. Dealership wanted $179 for it but an auto parts store was $91 so I went with them. But it's all good in the hood now. Thanks for your attention!